# Scrape data from akamai visualisation tool

Tags: web-scraping, visualization, akamai

I am currently working on a project for which I need to monitor some data from the akamai platform as visualised here: http://www.akamai.com/html/technology/dataviz3.html .

I did quite a bit of research, but did not manage to successfully scrape data from the swf objects. If anyone has any idea on how this could be done, I would be grateful to hear.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to so is use something like the Firefox [Firebug addon](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what the webpage is downloading.

[image]

So in the case of this page, it looks like all the data it uses is from:

http://wwwnui.akamai.com/datavis/pview_feed.xml

http://wwwnui.akamai.com/datavis/visitors_feed.xml

http://wwwnui.akamai.com/datavis/media_feed.xml

Then you can parse the data with [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) and do with it what you want.